# How to create green line border around an element in .cs file and XAML file

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, border

I would like to create a border over the `WindowsFormsHost`. How to do so?

In .cs file:

```
 WindowsFormsHost Host = new WindowsFormsHost();
```

and in the xaml:

```
 <WindowsFormsHost x:Name="Host"></WindowsFormsHost>
```

Answer (score 3):

The [`System.Windows.Border`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.border(v=vs.110).aspx) class is a type of `Decorator`, which means it can have a single [`Child`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.decorator.child(v=vs.110).aspx) element. In this case, your child would be the `WindowsFormsHost`.

**XAML:**

```
<Border BorderBrush="Green" BorderThickness="1">
   <WindowsFormsHost x:Name="Host"></WindowsFormsHost>
</Border>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the [border](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.border%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class:

xaml:

```
<Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Green">
    <WindowsFormsHost x:Name="Host"></WindowsFormsHost>
</Border>
```

cs:

```
var myBorder = new Border();
myBorder.BorderBrush = Brushes.Green;
myBorder.BorderThickness = new Thickness(1);
myBorder.Child = new WindowsFormsHost();
```